# How to compare 2 files having random numbers in non sequential order?

Tags: python, awk

There are 2 files named compare 1.txt and compare2.txt having random numbers in non-sequential order

cat compare1.txt

```
57
11
13
3
889
014
91
```

cat compare2.txt

```
003
889
13
14
57
12
90
```

Aim

1. Output list of all the numbers which are present in compare1 but not in compare 2 and **vice versa**
2. If any number has zero in its prefix, ignore zeros while comparing ( basically the absolute value of number must be different to be treated as a  mismatch  )
   Example -  3 should be considered matching with 003 and 014 should be considered matching with 14, 008 with 8 etc

Note - It is not necessary that matching must necessarily happen on the same line.
A number present in the first line in compare1 should be considered matched even if that same number is present on other than the first line in compare2

Expected output

```
90
91
12
11
```

PS ( I don't necessarily need this exact order in expected output, just these 4 numbers in any order would do )

What I tried?

Obviously I didn't have hopes of getting the second condition correct, I tried only fulfilling the first condition but couldn't get correct results.
I had tried these commands

```
grep -Fxv -f compare1.txt compare2.txt && grep -Fxv -f compare2.txt compare1.txt
```

```
cat compare1.txt compare2.txt | sort |uniq
```

Edit - A Python solution is also fine

Comment: Are you ok with using python for this? It will be easier in that I think

Comment: @mettleap yes sure will do

Comment: `sed 's/^0*//' file1 file2 | sort -n | uniq -u`

Comment: @Cyrus working well thanks for a solution with sed

Comment: Can you have numbers like `7.0` in one file that should match `7` in the other? How about exponents?

Comment: @EdMorton nope such cases probably won't exisit in my case atleast, apart from normal matching only unique thing i needed was to ignore zeros in prefix while matching numbers

Comment: Are the numbers within a file always unique or could `3` appear multiple times **in one of the files** (includes variations of `3`, like `03`, etc.)? If so please include cases like that in your example so we can see how should that be handled (does `3` output once or twice if it appears twice in one file but never appears in the other file? what if it appears once in one file but twice in the other - does it get output once?)

Comment: @EdMorton yes a number can appear multiple times , it can be considered matched only if if appears multiple times in both files .if it appears twice in compare1 file and once in compare2 , i would want that number to be present in output once, if any number occurs twice in compare1 and is absent in compare2 , it should be present in output twice as well

Comment: Ok then you **really** need to include cases that cover that in your example as right now I doubt if any of the answers would do what you want.

Comment: @EdMorton i know , my current doesn't question really need that much conditions yet , although since you asked so i gave the ideal scenario in the rarest case if it ever occurs

Comment: Well, you already got answers to the question you did ask so i wouldn't actually change it now but if you wanted to ask a followup question with cases like that included I'm sure you'd get a good answer. It's easy to handle, it just isn't being handled currently because you didn't include it in this specific question.

Comment: Although i really appreciate your efforts to not just answer the exiting question but also think of rare possibilities

Comment: No problem - the sunny day stuff is always trivial, 80% of software engineering is thinking up and covering the "what else could happen" cases :-).

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Could you please try following, written and tested with shown samples in GNU `awk`.

```
awk '
{
  $0=$0+0
}
FNR==NR{
  a[$0]
  next
}
($0 in a){
  b[$0]
  next
}
{ print }
END{
  for(j in a){
    if(!(j in b)){ print j }
  }
}
'  compare1.txt compare2.txt
```

***Explanation:*** Adding detailed explanation for above.

```
awk '                                ##Starting awk program from here.
{
  $0=$0+0                            ##Adding 0 will remove extra zeros from current line,considering that your file doesn't have float values.
}
FNR==NR{                             ##Checking condition FNR==NR which will be TRUE when 1st Input_file is being read.
  a[$0]                              ##Creating array a with index of current line here.
  next                               ##next will skip all further statements from here.
}
($0 in a){                           ##Checking condition if current line is present in a then do following.
  b[$0]                              ##Creating array b with index of current line.
  next                               ##next will skip all further statements from here.
}
{ print }                                   ##will print current line from 2nd Input_file here.
END{                                 ##Starting END block of this code from here.
  for(j in a){                       ##Traversing through array a here.
    if(!(j in b)){ print j }         ##Checking condition if current index value is NOT present in b then print that index.
  }
}
'  compare1.txt compare2.txt         ##Mentioning Input_file names here.
```

Comment: Working perfectly , you are a awk legend

Comment: @Sachin, your welcome and thank you for nice words :)  keep posting and keep learning on this great site cheers :)

Comment: I was thinking you could simplify your script by deleting from `a[]` instead of adding to `b[]` (replace `b[$0]` with `delete a[$0]` and then I THINK you don't need the `if` in the END section). That'd work for the given sample input/output but it'd produce different behavior from your current script if duplicate values exist in either file so [I've asked the OP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62495381/how-to-compare-2-files-having-random-numbers-in-non-sequential-order/62499047?noredirect=1#comment110529138_62495381) if that can happen and, if so, how it should be handled.

Comment: btw - just wanted to mention your coding style has improved vastly over the past year or so - nice work!

Comment: @EdMorton, I thought the same keeping duplicate thing in mind sir, thank you for your suggestion sir as usual loved it :)

Comment: @EdMorton, THANKS a TON sir for your appreciation you have huge contribution in it honestly. You made my day honestly thank you sir thank you :) :)

Comment: @EdMorton, one more thing sir, because of load of work sometime I couldn't follow your some nice recommendations because of being in multiple things so please don't mind that sir :)

Comment: No problem at all, I hadn't noticed that in any way.

Comment: @Sachin, as per Ed sir's suggestion please open a new thread for same which is recommended also one thread one question only cheers :)

Comment: `you are a awk legend` that is so true ;-)

Answer (score 6):

Here's how to do what you want just using awk:

```
$ awk '{$0+=0} NR==FNR{a[$0];next} !($0 in a)' compare1.txt compare2.txt
12
90

$ awk '{$0+=0} NR==FNR{a[$0];next} !($0 in a)' compare2.txt compare1.txt
11
91
```

but this is the job that `comm` exists to do so here's how you could use that to get all differences and common lines at once. In the following output  col1 is compare1.txt only, col2 is compare2.txt only, col3 is common between both files:

```
$ comm <(awk '{print $0+0}' compare1.txt | sort) <(awk '{print $0+0}' compare2.txt | sort)
11
    12
        13
        14
        3
        57
        889
    90
91
```

or to get each result individually:

```
$ comm -23 <(awk '{print $0+0}' compare1.txt | sort) <(awk '{print $0+0}' compare2.txt | sort)
11
91

$ comm -13 <(awk '{print $0+0}' compare1.txt | sort) <(awk '{print $0+0}' compare2.txt | sort)
12
90

$ comm -12 <(awk '{print $0+0}' compare1.txt | sort) <(awk '{print $0+0}' compare2.txt | sort)
13
14
3
57
889
```

Answer (score 3):

Given those two files, in Python, you can use a symmetric difference of sets:

```
with open(f1) as f:         # read the first file into a set
    s1={int(e) for e in f}
    
with open(f2) as f:         # read the second file into a set
    s2={int(e) for e in f}
    
print(s2 ^ s1)              # symmetric difference of those two sets
# {11, 12, 90, 91}
```

Which can be further simplified to:

```
with open(f1) as f1, open(f2) as f2:
    print({int(e) for e in f1} ^ {int(e) for e in f2})
```

More about Python sets [in the documents](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#set)

Answer (score 1):

I think I heard somewhere that a Ruby solution would be OK, so I will give two, but if Ruby is on the black list, at least one of the methods can be easily translated to a language on the approved list (no knowledge of Ruby required). The first method uses sets, which Ruby implements with hashes under the covers. The second method uses hashes. I've provided the latter should the language of choice not support set objects.

The main thing is to use a method that is close to O(n) in computational complexity, where `n` is the sum of the sizes of the two arrays. I say "close to" O(n) because the methods I suggest use hashes, directly or indirectly, and hash lookups are not quite O(1). The conventional approach to this problem, enumerating the second array for each element of the first, and vice-versa, has a computational complexity of O(n<sup>2</sup>).

We are given two arrays:

```
arr1 = ["57", "11", "13", "3", "889", "014", "91"] 
arr2 = ["003", "889", "13", "14", "57", "12", "90"]
```

**Use sets**

```
require 'set'

def not_in_other(a1, a2)
  st = a2.map(&:to_i).to_set
  a1.reject { |s| st.include?(s.to_i) }
end

not_in_other(arr1, arr2) + not_in_other(arr1, arr2)
  #=> ["11", "91", "11", "91"]
```

Note:

```
a = arr2.map(&:to_i)
  #=> [3, 889, 13, 14, 57, 12, 90] 
a.to_set
  #=> #<Set: {3, 889, 13, 14, 57, 12, 90}>
```

**Use hashes**

*Step 1: Construct a hash for each array*

```
def hashify(arr)
  arr.each_with_object({}) { |s,h| h[s.to_i] = s }
end

h1 = hashify(arr1)
  #=> {57=>"57", 11=>"11", 13=>"13", 3=>"03", 889=>"889",
  #    14=>"014", 91=>"91"} 
h2 = hashify(arr2)
  #=> {3=>"003", 889=>"889", 13=>"13", 12=>"12", 14=>"14",
  #    57=>"57", 90=>"90"}
```

The meanings of these hashes (whose keys are integers) should be self-evident.

*Step 2: Determine which keys in each hash are not present in the other hash*

```
keys1 = h1.keys
  #=> [57, 11, 13, 3, 889, 14, 91] 
keys2.keys
  #=> [3, 889, 13, 12, 14, 57, 90] 

keepers1 = keys1.reject { |k| h2.key?(k) }
  #=> [11, 91] 
keepers2 = keys2.reject { |k| h1.key?(k) }
  #=> [12, 90]
```

One could alternatively write:

```
keepers1 = keys1 - keys2
keepers2 = keys2 - keys1
```

I expect this would be O(n), but that would depend on the implementation.

*Step 3: Obtain the values of `h1` for keys `keepers1` and of `h2` for keys `keepers2`, and combine them*

```
h1.values_at(*keepers1) + h2.values_at(*keepers2)
  #=> ["11", "91", "12", "90"]
```

Comment: Why not use a Ruby set with `enum` to do this?

Comment: @dawg, I am a fool. An utter fool! It's good to be reminded of that from time-to-time. I initially considered using sets, but rejected the idea due to rushed and faulty reasoning. I've edited my answer. I see you left an answer using Python sets. Good on you!

Comment: Can't you just do `arr1.map(&:to_i).to_set ^ arr2.map(&:to_i).to_set`?

Comment: @dawg, all this time I've assumed the OP wanted an array of strings from the given arrays returned. I'm now wondering if an array of integers is wanted or would suffice, which is an easier problem. The question is not clear on that.

Answer (score 0):

Using python, you can do the following,

```
import csv

def func(file1, file2):
    set1 = read_file_as_set(file1)
    set2 = read_file_as_set(file2)

    union = set1.union(set2) #find union first
    intersection = set1.intersection(set2) #find intersection
    return union.difference(intersection)


def read_file_as_set(file):
    result = set()

    with open(file) as csv_file:
        file_reader = csv.reader(csv_file)

        for line in file_reader:
            result.add(int(line[0]))

    return result

if __name__=='__main__':

    print func("path/to/first/file.csv","path/to/second/file.csv")
```

I am essentially reading both files as separate sets and returning (file1_set union file2_set) - (file1_set intersection with file2_set)

Answer (score 0):

Another alternative solution by one of my friend in python

```
list1 = set()
list2 = set()
with open('compare1.txt','r') as file1:
    for line in file1:
        if line != '\n':
            list1.add(int(line))

with open('compare2.txt','r') as file2:
    for line in file2:
        if line != '\n':
            list2.add(int(line))

list3 = list1.symmetric_difference(list2)

for number in list3:
    print(number)
```

Answer (score 0):

Another solution in python:

```
x = [int(x) for x in open("compare1.txt")]
y = [int(x) for x in open("compare2.txt")]
z = []

for i in x:
    if (i not in y):
        z.append(i)


for i in y:
    if (i not in x):
        z.append(i)

for i in z:
    print(i)
```

Answer (score 0):

Besides handling leading zeros, your task can be solved just be using `diff` command, and filtering its output

```
diff "$FIRST" "$SECOND" \
        | awk '$1~/[<>]/{print $2}' # Only added or removed lines
```

You can get rid of leading zeros with `bc`

```
FIRST=${1:-first file should be specified}
SECOND=${2:-second file should be specified}
normalize() {
    bc < "$1" | sort --numeric
}
diff <(normalize "$FIRST") <(normalize "$SECOND") \
        | awk '$1~/[<>]/{print $2}'
```

Note that, [process subsitution](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Process-Substitution) syntax `<(command)` is a [bashism](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/Bashism), you will need to use a temporary file instead for POSIX complience.