# How to compare 2 files having multiple occurances of a number and output the additional occurance?

Tags: awk

Currently i am using a awk script to compare 2 files having random numbers in non sequential order.
It works perfect , but there is just one future condition i would like to fulfill.

Current awk function

```
awk '
{
  $0=$0+0
}
FNR==NR{
  a[$0]
  next
}
($0 in a){
  b[$0]
  next
}
{ print }
END{
  for(j in a){
    if(!(j in b)){ print j }
  }
}
'  compare1.txt compare2.txt
```

What the the function accomplishes currently ?

1. It outputs list of all the numbers which are present in compare1 but not in compare 2 and vice versa
2. If any number has zero in its prefix, ignore zeros while comparing ( basically the absolute value of number must be different to be treated as a mismatch ) Example - 3 should be considered matching with 003 and 014 should be considered matching with 14, 008 with 8 etc
3. As required It also considers a number matched even if they are not necessarily on the same line in both files

**Required additional condition**

In its current form , this functions works in such a way that if a file has multiple occurances of a number and other file has even one occurance of that same number , it considers the number matched for both repetitions.
I need the awk function to be edited to output any additional occurrence of a number

cat compare1.txt

```
57
11
13
3
889
014
91
775
```

cat compare2.txt

```
003
889
13
14
57
12
90
775
775
```

Expected output

```
12
90
11
91
**775**
```

The number marked here at end is currently not being shown in output in my present awk function ( 2 occurances - 1 occurrence )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you just need to count the occurrences and account for it in matching...

```
$ awk '{k=$0+0} 
       NR==FNR {a[k]++; next} 
       !(k in a && a[k]-->0); 
       END {for(k in a) while(a[k]-->0) print k}' file1 file2

12
90
775
11
91
```

note that as in your original script there is no absolute value comparison, which you can add easily by just changing `k` in the first line.

Comment: I tried the function , its working for my question well but doesn't seem work work universally , i added same number 5 times in 1 file and 2 times in other , but its being printed in output only 1 time instead of printing it 3 times , example added below

Comment: see the updated version, for that you have to print as many times as left in the array.

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned at https://stackoverflow.com/a/62499047/1745001, this is the job that `comm` exists to do:

```
$ comm -3 <(awk '{print $0+0}' compare1.txt | sort) <(awk '{print $0+0}' compare2.txt | sort)
11
    12
    775
    90
91
```

and to get rid of the white space:

```
$ comm -3 <(awk '{print $0+0}' compare1.txt | sort) <(awk '{print $0+0}' compare2.txt | sort) |
    awk '{print $1}'
11
12
775
90
91
```

Comment: how the tables turned!  `$ f() { awk '{print +$0}' "$1" | sort; }; comm -3 <(f file1) <(f file2) | tr -d '\t'`